# AWS EC2 linux console tools not working with EC2 permissions

Tags: amazon-ec2

I've spent hours and I found no solution.
I got the latest Debian marketplace image running and try to use the "aws" tools from command line.

I created an IAM user and gave the user every single permission available, including poweruser, ec2 full access, administrator.

```
aws  ec2 describe-addresses

A client error (AuthFailure) occurred when calling the DescribeAddresses operation: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
```

However I can use all non EC2 parts.
I can do any "aws iam" command, no issues at all.
I could create a user and give it any accessrights but I may not list instances!
This is not an authentication error ..

Date is NTP synced, however as "aws iam" commands all work perfectly it's not an API issue.

I am at the end of my wits. There i no permission left I could give that user.
I tried different access keys, same situation.
I tried waiting for an hour, no luck.

Here the EC2 Full access role the user has:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "ec2:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "elasticloadbalancing:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "cloudwatch:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "autoscaling:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Manager using the web console of AWS.

Comment: I've just installed the conventional ec2-tools (java ones) and everything works just fine.
Whatever is going on here, there is a major issue with the python based aws tools.

It's definitely not a role or right problem, it makes no sense that the "old" toolset works fine with the AWS API and the new toolset complains about permission issues (and it got damn administrative ones..)

Comment: Definitely a configuration issue. Where do you store the AWS credentials?

Comment: I can guarantee its not a configuration issue.
I used "aws configure" which stores it in the .aws/config file

When using "aws iam" i could test adding and removing rights from the user and it had effect. 
So aws IS using the correct credentials and loading them from the config file, otherwise the IAM functions would not work.

Same credentials using the java based ec2 tools worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were hitting your EIP limit. I was updating a Cloudformation stack yesterday and was getting the error..

> AccessDenied. User doesn't have permission to call ec2:DescribeAddresses

..even though I was running with full admin rights. Turned out the error was a red-herring and the problem was I was hitting my EIP limit. Requested an EIP limit increase and that fixed it.